# Plotting multiple trendlines in one graph in Rstudio

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've got a data set of 3 different measurements of the same variable (same x-axis, different procedures) and I would like to combine their trendlines in one graph.

dataset:

concentratie_G6P Inhibitor_Cu_ionen Inhibitor_glucosamine Zonder_inhibitor

1 0.00 0.0019 0.0000 0.0000

2 1.88 0.0448 0.0362 0.0185

3 3.75 0.0134 0.0467 0.0175

4 7.50 0.0470 0.0397 0.0796

5 15.00 0.0285 0.0532 0.0541

6 30.00 0.0324 0.0433 0.0217

Is there any way to display the points of these datasets and a legend?

What I've tried so far:

```
 figuur <- ggplot()+ geom_smooth(data=tabel_Cu, se=FALSE, show.legend = T, fill="black", color = "black" ,aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_Cu_ionen))+geom_smooth(data = tabel_Zonder, se=FALSE, show.legend=T, fill="red", color="red", aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Zonder_inhibitor))+geom_smooth(data = tabel_glucosamine, se=FALSE, show.legend=T, fill="blue", aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_glucosamine))+theme_light()+labs(x="concentratie G6P (µM)", y="DA/min")+geom_point()
print(figuur)
```

This gives me the desired figure, but I can't seem to find a way to display the points of the dataset and a legend.

thanks in advance for helping me out!

Answer (score 0):

To give a plot with multiple dataframes one `legend`, you can manually scale the colors using `scale_color_manual`. In the `labels` argument you can change the names seen in the legend. You can use the following code:

```
tabel_Cu <- data.frame(concentratie_G6P = c(0, 1.88, 3.75, 7.5, 15, 30),
                       Inhibitor_Cu_ionen = c(0.0019, 0.0448, 0.0134, 0.047, 0.0285, 0.0324))

tabel_Zonder <- data.frame(concentratie_G6P = c(0, 1.88, 3.75, 7.5, 15, 30),
                           Zonder_inhibitor = c(0, 0.0185, 0.0175, 0.0796, 0.0541, 0.0217))

tabel_glucosamine <- data.frame(concentratie_G6P = c(0, 1.88, 3.75, 7.5, 15, 30),
                                Inhibitor_glucosamine = c(0, 0.0362, 0.0467, 0.0397, 0.0532, 0.0433))

library(tidyverse)

figuur <- ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data = tabel_Cu, aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_Cu_ionen, color = "black")) + 
  geom_point(data = tabel_Zonder, aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Zonder_inhibitor, color = "red")) + 
  geom_point(data = tabel_glucosamine, aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_glucosamine, color = "blue")) + 
  geom_smooth(data= tabel_Cu, se=FALSE, aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_Cu_ionen, color = "black")) + 
  geom_smooth(data = tabel_Zonder, se=FALSE, aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Zonder_inhibitor, color = "red")) + 
  geom_smooth(data = tabel_glucosamine, se=FALSE, aes(x=concentratie_G6P, y=Inhibitor_glucosamine, color = "blue")) + 
  theme_light() + 
  labs(x="concentratie G6P (µM)", y="DA/min") + 
  scale_color_manual(
    values = c("black", "red", "blue"),
    labels = c("black", "red", "blue"))
print(figuur)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I do know about the geom_line() function. The problem is that I need a trendline of each dataset of the experiment and have to combine them in one graph (sharing the same x- and y-axis).  I've added an image of the trendlines I would like to combine. Thank you for taking your time to help me!

Comment: @JorisVerhelst, I just edited my answer using the package `patchwork`

Comment: this wasn't quite what I was looking for, but I've found a solution myself: I have edited my original post to include the code. Maybe you do know a way to display the points of the diferent datasets and a legend?

Comment: @JorisVerhelst, I changed the code which displays the points of the different datasets with a legend.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is awesome. Exactly what I'm looking for